# iOS: How to completely uninstall app and all data associated with app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, wkwebview

I'm experience something similar at this issue:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175897/completely-uninstall-ios-
app-and-all-associated-data

My question to you guys is what can I do or what can implement for user can remover all the user data and app data associated with the app?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Hard to help if you don't provide any information about where your app stores its data.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the data from the device by deleting the app normally. Simply long press on the app icon then hit the X button. In many cases, you will not be able to remove your information from the apps servers.